# Read Output of an application

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have an application from where I suppose to run another console based exe and read the output of that console application? Assume the console application is third party exe which writing it using `printf`.

Comment: You can do this with `CreateProcess` - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Currently I am using CreateProcess to launch third party exe but the link say I have make changes in the childExe also. Means here in Third party exe which is not possible.

Comment: @CrazyC AFAIK, you don't need to modify the child exe. Where does it say that? (The bit with pipe communication in the example is for the specific example - the `printf` should also show up in the parent.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `CreateProcess()` to run the console app, then you can use the `STARTUPINFO` struct to specify your own STDIN/OUT/ERR handles for the console to use.  Create anonymous pipes via `CreatePipe()` for that purpose, then you can read/write the pipes using `ReadFile()` and `WriteFile()` as needed.

There is an example on MSDN:

[Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)